# Get WMI CPU Values using Perl

Tags: perl, wmi

I'm Trying go GET CPU values using WMI classes but with no lucky.

1. With the class `Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor`, I'm always getting the same values they don't change...
2. With the WMI class `Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor`, the value of `PercentProcessorTime` is equal to `PercentProcessorTime`, something is wrong.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::OLE;
use Data::Dumper;

my $class = "Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor";
my $key = 'Name';

my @properties = qw(PercentIdleTime PercentProcessorTime PercentPrivilegedTimePercentUserTime PercentInterruptTime);
my $wmi = Win32::OLE->GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
    or die "Failed getobject\n";

my $list, my $v;

$list = $wmi->InstancesOf("$class")
    or die "Failed getobject\n";
my $hash;
foreach $v (in $list) {        
    $hash->{$v->{$key}}->{$_}  = $v->{$_} for @properties;
}

print Dumper $hash;

#-------------------
# Using Otehr class    
$class = 'Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor';

$wmi = Win32::OLE->GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
    or die "Failed getobject\n";

$list = $wmi->InstancesOf("$class")
    or die "Failed getobject\n";
foreach $v (in $list) {        
    $hash->{$v->{$key}}->{$_}  = $v->{$_} for @properties;
}

print Dumper $hash;
```

OUTPUT:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '0' => {
                   'PercentPrivilegedTime' => '0',
                   'PercentIdleTime' => '0',
                   'PercentInterruptTime' => '0',
                   'PercentUserTime' => '0',
                   'PercentProcessorTime' => '100'
                 },
          '_Total' => {
                        'PercentPrivilegedTime' => '0',
                        'PercentIdleTime' => '0',
                        'PercentInterruptTime' => '0',
                        'PercentUserTime' => '0',
                        'PercentProcessorTime' => '100'
                      }
        };
$VAR1 = {
          '0' => {
                   'PercentPrivilegedTime' => '15442905808',
                   'PercentIdleTime' => '2505024948976',
                   'PercentInterruptTime' => '1866684160',
                   'PercentUserTime' => '682681648',
                   'PercentProcessorTime' => '2505024948976'
                 },
          '_Total' => {
                        'PercentPrivilegedTime' => '15442905808',
                        'PercentIdleTime' => '2505024948976',
                        'PercentInterruptTime' => '1866684160',
                        'PercentUserTime' => '682681648',
                        'PercentProcessorTime' => '2505024948976'
                      }
        };
```

Comment: `-w` and `use warnings` are redundant in this case. `-w` is global whereas `use warnings` pragma can be enabled and disabled within blocks, or by `no warnings`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the  script that i've done to collect CPU info:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::OLE;


my $interval = 1;
my $key = 'Name';
my @properties = qw(PercentIdleTime PercentProcessorTime PercentPrivilegedTime PercentUserTime PercentInterruptTime TimeStamp_Sys100NS);

my $hash1 = {};

my $wmi = Win32::OLE->GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
    or die "Failed to get object\n";


my $list = $wmi->InstancesOf('Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor')
    or die "Failed to get instance object\n";

my $v;  
foreach $v (in $list) {         
        map{$hash1->{$v->{$key}}->{$_}  = $v->{$_} }@properties;
}

while(sleep 1){

    $list = $wmi->InstancesOf('Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor')
        or die "Failed to get instance object\n";

    my $hash = {};
    foreach $v (in $list) {         
        map{$hash->{$v->{$key}}->{$_}  = $v->{$_} }@properties;
    }

    my $cpu_time = sprintf("%.2f", (1 - get_value($hash1->{'_Total'}, $hash->{'_Total'}, 'PercentProcessorTime' )) * 100);
    my $cpu_idle = sprintf("%.2f", 100-$cpu_time);
    my $cpu_user = sprintf("%.2f", get_value($hash1->{'_Total'}, $hash->{'_Total'}, 'PercentUserTime' )* 100);
    my $cpu_priv = sprintf("%.2f", get_value($hash1->{'_Total'}, $hash->{'_Total'}, 'PercentPrivilegedTime' )* 100);
    my $cpu_int = sprintf("%.2f", get_value($hash1->{'_Total'}, $hash->{'_Total'}, 'PercentInterruptTime' )* 100);      
    printf "CPU Time %s %% , privileged %s %% , user %s %%, interrupt %s %%\n", $cpu_time,$cpu_priv,$cpu_user,$cpu_int;

    $hash1 = $hash;
}


exit;

sub get_value {
    my $h1 = shift;
    my $h2 = shift;
    my $property = shift;
    return (($h2->{$property} - $h1->{$property})/($h2->{'TimeStamp_Sys100NS'}-$h1->{'TimeStamp_Sys100NS'}));
}
```

Output sample:

```
CPU Time 2.03 % , privileged 1.96 % , user 0.00 %, interrupt 0.00 %
CPU Time 1.87 % , privileged 1.96 % , user 0.00 %, interrupt 0.00 %
CPU Time 2.16 % , privileged 1.96 % , user 0.00 %, interrupt 0.00 %
CPU Time 1.76 % , privileged 1.96 % , user 0.00 %, interrupt 0.00 %
CPU Time 2.19 % , privileged 1.96 % , user 0.00 %, interrupt 0.00 %
CPU Time 1.77 % , privileged 1.96 % , user 0.00 %, interrupt 0.00 %
CPU Time 1.98 % , privileged 1.96 % , user 0.00 %, interrupt 0.00 %
CPU Time 1.93 % , privileged 1.96 % , user 0.00 %, interrupt 0.00 %
CPU Time 2.08 % , privileged 1.96 % , user 0.00 %, interrupt 0.00 %
CPU Time 2.84 % , privileged 2.94 % , user 0.00 %, interrupt 0.00 %
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit to make the answer more precise:**

<strike>Retrieving instances of these classes</strike> `Win32::OLE->GetObject(...)` gets you a **snapshot** of the current state of the processors. To see how processor states change over time, you will need to <strike>get separate instances at</strike> make separate calls to `Win32::OLE->GetObject` at separate times.

Comment: I've done a loop, getting always new instances, and the results are similar.... That won't solvit. Did you test the script?

Comment: @golden PT: Answer edited. Make sure the call to `GetObject(...)` is *inside* the loop, too.

Comment: For the first Dump i'm getting always the same values.\

Comment: Do you mean you're always getting `PercentProcessorTime => 100`? What if you run the script while your machine isn't so busy?