# What is the alternative of Linux module (GTop->new->proc_mem($$)) in windows

Tags: perl, perl-module

I want to use GTop->new->proc_mem($$) function in windows but I dint find this folder in window can you please suggest me how I can use this module in windows.. for perl programing .

Answer (score 1):

not sure if there's a single lib for all of GTop's capabilities.

For memory you could try this:
([Get WMI Memory Values using Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726968/get-wmi-memory-values-using-perl))

As for CPU you could see:
([Get WMI CPU Values using Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750582/get-wmi-cpu-values-using-perl))
or (http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=951420)